# about non normality of Sorgenfrey plane

Tags: general-topology

There is a classical theorem saying that a regular space with a countable basis is normal.  The Sorgenfrey plane is regular since it is the product of two regular spaces (which in fact are normal) and it has a countable basis since it is separable which would say that it should be normal, however, it is NOT.

What am I thinking wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Countable basis $\Longrightarrow$ separable | in general topological spaces.

Separable $\Longrightarrow$ countable basis | only in *metrizable* topological spaces.

---

Sorgenfrey’s plane is not metrizable. It is separable, but does not admit a countable basis.

Comment: And the Sorgenfrey line itself also has no countable base, despite being separable.